# laravel auto complete Text View

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I am using Laravel  5.2.

here is my code

```
    //for header
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('src/js/jquery-1.10.2.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('src/js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>  
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('src/css/jquery-ui.css') }}">  
        </head>

//body

<div class="col-sm-6 feature" >
        <div class="ui-widget">
          <label for="skills">Skills: </label>
          <input type="text" class="search_keyword" id="skills" placeholder="Search.." name="skills" />
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
                     source: "{{URL::route('auto')}}"
                    //source: ["a","b"]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div><!-- end feature -->

//route

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/auto', [
    'uses' => 'SearchController@AutoSug',
    'as' => 'auto'
    ]);


//controller

class SearchController extends Controller
{

public function AutoSug()
    {
        $auto_s = DB::table('skills')
                ->pluck('skill');

        return response()->json($auto_s);

    }

}
```

Now problem is when I browse manually the link {{URL::route('auto')}} which says as here [json view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPNWx.png)

So the problem is it does not give as it should be see here 
[main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uZn5.png)

But if I change the code "{{URL::route('auto')}}" to source: ["a","b"]. It outputs properly. So where might be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the solution.

For javascript please write as follows

```
$(function()
      {
           $( "#q" ).autocomplete({
            source: "{{URL('auto')}}",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
            $( "#q" ).val(ui.item.value);
            }       
             });
       });
```

For controller please add as follows

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use App\Product;
    use DB;

    class SearchController extends Controller
    {

    public function autoComplete()
        {

            $term = Input::get('term');

            $results = array();

            $queries = DB::table('skills')
            ->where('skill', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
            ->take(9)->get();

        foreach ($queries as $query)
        {
            $results[] = [ 'id' => $query->ID, 'value' => $query->skill];
        }


        return response()->json($results);
        }

    }
```

The problem was in controller it was getting null value for get variable and query builder was returning all the result from the database.I have added a library and associate variable as follows and solved the issue.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
$term = Input::get('term');
```

Hope it will help others for same issue.

I hope the following links will be helpful.

1. https://gist.github.com/imranismail/10200241?signup=true
2. https://gist.github.com/manoj-nandakumar/11beb90916dfbdc6af7a